# "poster" vs "display". Can display be used to refer to an informative paper like a poster?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

I was wondering if it's correct to say

> We can put a display on the glass part of the door to improve the room's privacy. This would look interesting from the outside, too.

As far as I know, I haven't seen display being used for referring to a piece of paper.

However, I found this in Oxford Dictionary

- The event will include displays from wine producers, whisky distillers and champagne tasters.

Isn't "poster" a better choice? Is there any difference between poster and display in this context?

Answer (score 2):

A poster is a sheet of paper with something printed on it.

A display at an event (e. g. from a wine producer) would be a much larger installation, like an open half-booth—something like [this](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/visitors-look-at-a-stand-of-a-sparkling-wine-producer-on-news-photo/141913381) or [this](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/a598fb19121705.57fbec1b582a8.png).

"Display" cannot be used instead of a "poster".

Comment: Yes. A "display" is normally understood to be something 3-dimensional. Samples of the company's products, a model, that sort of thing. A "poster" is a large piece of paper or light cardstock with something printed on it. I'd say "display" is doubly inapplicable here as the primary purpose of putting up the paper is not to "display" anything but to hide something -- the interior of the room.